# IndexError: list index out of range 4

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo un programa que busca funciones me arroja este problema:

```
while lista[a] != (' ' or '' or '\n' or '\t' ):
```

> IndexError: list index out of range

El programa entero es este:

```
def look_for_def (lista):
    i = 0
    a = 0
    func = ''
    defi = []
    while i < len(lista):
        if (lista[i] =='d') and (lista[i + 1] =='e') and (lista[i + 2] == 'f') \
        and (lista[i + 3] == ' '):
            a = i + 3
            while lista[a] == ' ':
                a += 1
            while lista[a] not in {' ', '' ,'\n', '\t'}:
                func += lista[a]
                a += 1
            defi.append(func)
            func = ''
        i += 1
    return defi
```

Un texto  de  entrada seria ['d', 'e', 'f', '  ', 'f', 'u', 'c', 't']

El texto que deberia salir seria ['funct']

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a [es.so] ¿Podrías agregar un ejemplo de la lista de entrada y la salida esperada para poder reproducir el código más fácilmente? Por cierto `(' ' or '' or '\n' or '\t' )` retorna `' '`, por lo que la comparación equivale a `lista[a] != ' '`, creo que lo que deseas es `lista[a] != ' ' and  lista[a] != '' and lista[a] != '\n' and lista[a] != '\t' :` o usando el operador de pertenencia: `lista[a] not in {' ', '' , '\n', '\t' }`. Para añadir información a la pregunta usa el botón [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/151500/edit) que hay debajo de ella. Un saludo.

Comment: Holaa, primero muchas gracias por ayudarme @FJSevilla , es que soy principiante en esto. Un texto de entrada seria [[' ', 'd', 'e', 'f', ' ', ' ', 'p', 'e', 'p', 'e']] y el de salida seria [pepe]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día, a mi me funciono de la siguiente manera, si quieres analizarlo y fijarte que hice diferente, o úsalo de esa misma manera.
Las 2 grandes diferencias que vas a notar es que yo agregue deliberadamente un espacio a la lista a analizar, y la otra es que 'i siempre aumentaba lo mismo que a, para que la salida no este sumando espacios en blanco.

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Thu Mar 29 06:17:42 2018

@author: Xonem
"""

#x = [' ', 'd', 'e', 'f', ' ', ' ', 'p', 'e', 'p', 'e']
x = [' ', 'd', 'e', 'f', ' ', ' ', 'p', 'e', 'p', 'e','p', 'e', 'p', 'e','p', 'e', 'p', 'e']

def look_for_def (lista):
    lista.append(' ')
    i = 0
    a = 0
    func = ''
    defi = []
    while i < len(lista):
        if (lista[i] =='d') and (lista[i + 1] =='e') and (lista[i + 2] == 'f') \
        and (lista[i + 3] == ' '):
            a = i + 3
            i+=3
            while lista[a] == ' ':
                a += 1
                i+=1
            while lista[a] != (' ' or '' or '\n' or '\t'):

                func += lista[a]
                a += 1
                i+=1
                defi.append(func[len(func)-1])



        i += 1
    return defi

y= look_for_def(x)
print(y)
```

Comment: Me ha funcionado. Muchas Gracias!! @Xonem